# Can anyone explain why this regex fails?

Tags: regex

The regex

```
[a-z0-9]{1,10}_([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])([2000-2099]{4}).cta$
```

This string fails

```
abscriprod_01152013.cta
```

This string works

```
abscriprod_11152012.cta
```

It appears that any year ending in 3-8 fails, but I can't see why.

P.S. I suck at RegEx, so if there is a blatant mistake here, don't laugh :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read some regular expression manual, for example [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html). The regular expression that you use contains multiple flaws:

1. A character class that does only contain one character as in `/[0]/` is better written simply as `/0/`.
2. A `/./` will match any character (except newline). To match the literal dot, you have to escape it: `/\./`.
3. A character class that should match '1' or '2' may not be written `/[1|2]/` but rather `/[12]/` without the pipe in the middle. If you put the pipe there, it will match one of the 3 characters '1', '2', or '|'.
4. To match numbers in the range 2000 to 2099, you may not use `/[2000-2099]/` as such a character class will match one of the characters '0', '1' (because of the 0-2), '2', or '9'. Instead, you could use `/20\d\d/`.

h2h

Answer (score 1):

It fails because of this bit:

```
[2000-2099]{4}
```

Which is really saying:

One of the characters 2 or 0 from `200`

A character in the range 0 to 2 from `0-2`

Then one of the characters 0 or 9 from `099`

To match as I suspect you want a 4 digit year from 2000 to 2099 use:

```
20\d\d
```